# Are these phrases puns, idioms, quips, or something else?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is the grammatical term for phrases such as "The juice isn't worth the squeeze" and "*Listen* and *silent* have the same letters.  Coincidence?"

Comment: Maybe "siltent" instead of silence?  In any case could you show us some research you've done?

Comment: Listen and sil*ent*.

Comment: My apologies...I meant listen and silent.

Comment: Hi @Kate, welcome to ELU!  I edited the question for you.  If you want to make further changes, you can click on the 'edit' link that should appear just below the text of the question (along with other options: *share, edit, flag*).

Comment: I can't see that your two examples have anything in common. The first is a colloquial metaphorical saying. The second is a clever observation made into a witty remark.

Comment: @Kate Not sure what you are looking for exactly. The first one is just a colloquial phrase. The other 2 (silent and listen) are anagrams of each other. The word you may be look for is **anagram** (?).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your comment seems to imply that the OP's question is unanswerable (no commonalities), but you actually do answer the question: the first is an idiom, the second is a quip. (going by OP's options as listed)

Comment: @Kace36: It's more than just an anagram, though. There's a further connotation of a shared meaning (**not** a coincidence, as is sarcastically asked) as opposed to simply using the same letters. Another example would be stating that "mother in law" and "woman hitler" are anagrams. There's more to it than just the fact of it being an anagram (the implied shared meaning to a comical end).

Comment: @Flater That would be an answer (no; two answers) if OP had asked 'What are the grammatical terms for phrases such as (a) "The juice isn't worth the squeeze" and (b) "Listen and silent have the same letters. Coincidence?" '. OP implies a commonality I (and Kace36, above) don't see.

Answer (score -1):

I would say these are examples of a ***[saying](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/saying)***:

> A short, pithy, commonly known expression which generally offers
> advice or wisdom.

The *Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus* offers the following guide:

> CHOOSE THE RIGHT WORD
>
> **saying, adage, aphorism, apothegm, epigram, epigraph, maxim, proverb**
>
> “Once burned, twice shy” is an old **saying** about learning from your
> mistakes. In fact, sayings —a term used to describe any current or
> habitual expression of wisdom or truth—are a dime a dozen. **Proverbs**
> —sayings that are well known and often repeated, usually expressing
> metaphorically a truth based on common sense or practical
> experience—are just as plentiful (her favorite proverb was “A stitch
> in time saves nine”). An **adage** is a time-honored and widely known
> proverb, such as “Where there's smoke, there's fire.” A **maxim** offers a
> rule of conduct or action in the form of a proverb, such as “Neither a
> borrower nor a lender be.” **Epigram** and **epigraph** are often confused,
> but their meanings are quite separate. An epigram is a terse, witty,
> or satirical statement that often relies on a paradox for its effect
> (Oscar Wilde's well-known epigram that “The only way to get rid of
> temptation is to yield to it”). An epigraph, on the other hand, is a
> brief quotation used to introduce a piece of writing (he used a quote
> from T. S. Eliot as the epigraph to his new novel). An **aphorism**
> requires a little more thought than an epigram, since it aims to be
> profound rather than witty (she'd just finished reading a book of Mark
> Twain's aphorisms). An **apothegm** is a pointed and often startling
> aphorism, such as Samuel Johnson's remark that “Patriotism is the last
> refuge of a scoundrel.”.